# Is data becoming more or less concentrated globally?

Tags: trends

There are lots of books and research about the distribution of wealth, income, etc both at a national and a global level.

What is the trend with the data? Of course there are more and more data available openly. How about the data that is not open? How concentrated is it? Is the concentration increasing or decreasing? Is the fraction of open data increasing? Have there been any attempts to estimate this?